# removing border around button on tap

Tags: html, css

When I tap the button, this orange box around the button shows up. Is there any way to prevent it from showing up? [image]

Comment: Show you code and what you already tried (CSS and HTML in this case, but mainly CSS)

Answer (score 3):

You need to remove `button` border on focus by adding below `css`:

```
button:focus {outline:0;}
```

Comment: Yes that was it, Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You could use the **[outline](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_outline.asp)** property :

```
.yourButton:focus{
   outline:none;
}
```

Comment: This will not work you need to remove border on focus

Comment: Good point, will modify it